# How to remove usb3monitor.exe

Tags: windows-10, uninstall

This is a program that I think installed when I installed my motherboard drivers the other day, but I see no use in it and I've read its a kind of a keylogger, and I want to remove it. It originates from VIA Technologies. It isn't showing up on `Add or Remove Programs` in Windows 10, nor does it have and "uninstall.exe" in its folder. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What is `usb3monitor.exe` and how do I remove it?

> usb3monitor.exe executes as a process with the local user's privileges usually within the context of Windows Explorer. It is set to be start when the PC boots and any user logs into Windows (added to the Run registry key for the all users under the local machine).

Source [What is usb3Monitor.exe?](https://www.file.net/process/usb3monitor.exe.html)

If you really want to remove it you can:

- first stop the process using the task manager
- delete the appropriate key from the registry that starts it
- reboot

---

#### I see no use in it

It is provided by the manufacturer of your motherboard so we can assume it is required to ensure your USB device are working properly.

Remove at your own risk.

Comment: The process was included with motherboard drivers latest update, the USB devices are working as they should before it was even installed so I don't think its that necessary to have it.

Answer (score 0):

I've not heard of this but a quick google suggests that your motherboards USB3 ports might not operate correctly if this file is removed.

An easy test would be to open Task Manager `CTRL + SHIFT + ESC`, go to the processes or details tab and end task on the USB3Monitor.exe process. if everything is running OK then I would imagine you can remove it.

To remove, once the process is terminated you could simply rename the .EXE file to .OLD, this will stop it from executing but give you an easy roll back should it cause problems down the line.

Alternatively get a copy of [Sysinternals Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) and use that to search for where the USB3Monitor.exe is launched from and remove it. Once removed reboot and you will see that it is not running.

Careful with this one as you could cause problems if you make a change that you don't fully understand.